# HA-Namenode failover failed by killing the whole Server

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-zookeeper, high-availability, failover

I´m trying to set up an HA-Hdfs Cluster like the Apache-Doku explained.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html

When i kill the Prozess of der active Nameserver the failover works fine, but when i cause an bigger failture like unplugging the network, the standby namenode does not go active.
The standby node tries to set the active node to standby, but when the maschine died, establishing an SSH-connection would be difficult.
Is there anything that i´ve not seen?

This is what the  hadoop-hduser-zkfc-nn1.log says:

```
2016-09-27 15:03:11,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.NodeFencer: ====== Beginning Service Fencing Process... ======
2016-09-27 15:03:20,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.NodeFencer: Trying method 1/1: org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort(null)
2016-09-27 15:03:20,317 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort: Connecting to nn2.example.org...
2016-09-27 15:03:20,317 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort.jsch: Connecting to nn2.example.org port 22
2016-09-27 15:03:23,315 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort: Unable to connect to nn2.example.org as user hduser
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:386)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort.tryFence(SshFenceByTcpPort.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.NodeFencer.fence(NodeFencer.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.doFence(ZKFailoverController.java:532)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.fenceOldActive(ZKFailoverController.java:505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.access$1100(ZKFailoverController.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$ElectorCallbacks.fenceOldActive(ZKFailoverController.java:892)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector.fenceOldActive(ActiveStandbyElector.java:910)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector.becomeActive(ActiveStandbyElector.java:809)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector.processResult(ActiveStandbyElector.java:418)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:599)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)
2016-09-27 15:03:23,315 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ha.NodeFencer: Fencing method org.apache.hadoop.ha.SshFenceByTcpPort(null) was unsuccessful.
2016-09-27 15:03:23,315 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.ha.NodeFencer: Unable to fence service by any configured method.
2016-09-27 15:03:23,315 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Exception handling the winning of election
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to fence NameNode at nn2.example.org/172.16.1.188:8040
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.doFence(ZKFailoverController.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.fenceOldActive(ZKFailoverController.java:505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.access$1100(ZKFailoverController.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$ElectorCallbacks.fenceOldActive(ZKFailoverController.java:892)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector.fenceOldActive(ActiveStandbyElector.java:910)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector.becomeActive(ActiveStandbyElector.java:809)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector.processResult(ActiveStandbyElector.java:418)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:599)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)
2016-09-27 15:03:23,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Trying to re-establish ZK session
2016-09-27 15:03:23,325 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x3576b5e84d4003a closed
2016-09-27 15:03:24,329 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=nn1.example.org:2181,nn2.example.org:2181,dn1.example.org:2181,dn2.example.org:2181,dn3.example.org:2181 sessionTimeout=5000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector$WatcherWithClientRef@3bf4eda6
2016-09-27 15:03:24,335 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server nn1.example.org/172.16.1.187:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-09-27 15:03:24,342 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to nn1.example.org/172.16.1.187:2181, initiating session
2016-09-27 15:03:24,379 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server nn1.example.org/172.16.1.187:2181, sessionid = 0x1576b95292f0001, negotiated timeout = 5000
2016-09-27 15:03:24,386 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2016-09-27 15:03:24,403 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Session connected.
2016-09-27 15:03:24,407 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Checking for any old active which needs to be fenced...
2016-09-27 15:03:24,425 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Old node exists: 0a0a68612d636c757374657212036e6e321a1668646d617374657230322e7265696368656c742e646520e83e28d33e
2016-09-27 15:03:24,444 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController: Should fence: NameNode at nn2.example.org/172.16.1.188:8040
2016-09-27 15:03:27,315 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn2.example.org/172.16.1.188:8040. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=1, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-09-27 15:03:29,315 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ha.FailoverController: Unable to gracefully make NameNode at nn2.example.org/172.16.1.188:8040 standby (unable to connect)
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from  nn1.example.org/172.16.1.187 to nn2.example.org:8040 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:758)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.transitionToStandby(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.protocolPB.HAServiceProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.transitionToStandby(HAServiceProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.FailoverController.tryGracefulFence(FailoverController.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.doFence(ZKFailoverController.java:514)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.fenceOldActive(ZKFailoverController.java:505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.access$1100(ZKFailoverController.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$ElectorCallbacks.fenceOldActive(ZKFailoverController.java:892)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector.fenceOldActive(ActiveStandbyElector.java:910)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector.becomeActive(ActiveStandbyElector.java:809)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector.processResult(ActiveStandbyElector.java:418)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:599)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: Three questions out of curiosity: 1. Did you only unplug the network cable of the node that was supposed to fail? 2. Did hdfs actually break, or did you just get these errors? 3. Are you sure that all contents of the failed node were redundant (not secretly the only one to hold a metastore for instance?)

Comment: I have 5 Nodes. 2 Master and 3 Slaves. The Masters are nn1 and nn2. 1. Of course i have unplugged the network only of the active NN to check the failover. 2. the hdfs worked fine, but only in readonly-modus because no active NN 3. yes.

Comment: By the way, when i re-anable the network-connenction of the unplugges Server, the passive namenode can connect via ssh and do a failover and switch to active. Verry strange.

Comment: I am having same problem. But this problem occured when i stopped the active namenode and waited for sometime for failover to occur. fail over din't happened. Can anybody help?

Comment: @Krishnom can u please help? facing the same problem

Comment: @iammehrabala Can you write some details in a page. Any info about fix is very faint but i can help

Comment: @Krishnom Thanks for comment  but the problem is solved